# Caching Images in UICollectionViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, swift2

I am trying to cache images to prevent it from reloading constantly and crashing the app. So, I went to look at `apple's` implementation of `ImageCaching` which was written in `Objective-C` and had to replicate in swift. But, when I run and I try to cache, my app cache with an error of `fatal error: found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

## Swift Code

```
func updateCachedAssets() -> Void {
    let isViewVisible: Bool = self.isViewLoaded() && self.view.window != nil
    if !isViewVisible { return }

    //The preheat window is twice the height of the visible rect
    var preheatRect: CGRect = (self.collectionView?.bounds)!
    preheatRect = CGRectInset(preheatRect, 0.0, -0.5 * CGRectGetHeight(preheatRect))

    //Check if the collection view is showing an area that is significantly diferent to the last preheated area
    let delta: CGFloat = abs(CGRectGetMidY(preheatRect) - CGRectGetMidY(self.prevoiusPreheatRect))
    if delta > CGRectGetHeight((self.collectionView?.bounds)!)/3.0 {

        //Compute the assets to start caching and to stop caching
        let addedIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()
        let removedIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()

        self.computeDifferenceBetweenRect(self.prevoiusPreheatRect, andRect: preheatRect, removedHandler: { (removedRect) -> Void in
            let indexPaths: NSArray = [self.collectionView! .aapl_indexPathsForElementsInRect(removedRect)]
            removedIndexPaths.addObjectsFromArray(indexPaths as [AnyObject])
            }, addedHandler: { (addedRect) -> Void in
                let indexPaths: NSArray = [self.collectionView! .aapl_indexPathsForElementsInRect(addedRect)]
                addedIndexPaths.addObjectsFromArray(indexPaths as [AnyObject])
        })

        //print("AssetAtIndex", self.assetsAtIndexPaths(addedIndexPaths))
        let assetsToStartCaching: NSArray = self.assetsAtIndexPaths(addedIndexPaths)
        let assetsToStopCaching: NSArray = self.assetsAtIndexPaths(removedIndexPaths)

        //Update the assets the PHCachingImageManager is caching.
        self.imageManager.startCachingImagesForAssets(assetsToStartCaching as! [PHAsset], targetSize: AssetGridThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil)
        self.imageManager.startCachingImagesForAssets(assetsToStopCaching as! [PHAsset], targetSize: AssetGridThumbnailSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil)
        self.prevoiusPreheatRect = preheatRect
    }
}
```

## Objective-C

```
- (void)updateCachedAssets {
BOOL isViewVisible = [self isViewLoaded] && [[self view] window] != nil;
if (!isViewVisible) { return; }

// The preheat window is twice the height of the visible rect.
CGRect preheatRect = self.collectionView.bounds;
preheatRect = CGRectInset(preheatRect, 0.0f, -0.5f * CGRectGetHeight(preheatRect));

/*
    Check if the collection view is showing an area that is significantly
    different to the last preheated area.
 */
CGFloat delta = ABS(CGRectGetMidY(preheatRect) - CGRectGetMidY(self.previousPreheatRect));
if (delta > CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds) / 3.0f) {

    // Compute the assets to start caching and to stop caching.
    NSMutableArray *addedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *removedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self computeDifferenceBetweenRect:self.previousPreheatRect andRect:preheatRect removedHandler:^(CGRect removedRect) {
        NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView aapl_indexPathsForElementsInRect:removedRect];
        [removedIndexPaths addObjectsFromArray:indexPaths];
    } addedHandler:^(CGRect addedRect) {
        NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView aapl_indexPathsForElementsInRect:addedRect];
        [addedIndexPaths addObjectsFromArray:indexPaths];
    }];

    NSArray *assetsToStartCaching = [self assetsAtIndexPaths:addedIndexPaths];
    NSArray *assetsToStopCaching = [self assetsAtIndexPaths:removedIndexPaths];

    // Update the assets the PHCachingImageManager is caching.
    [self.imageManager startCachingImagesForAssets:assetsToStartCaching
                                        targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                       contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                           options:nil];
    [self.imageManager stopCachingImagesForAssets:assetsToStopCaching
                                       targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                          options:nil];

    // Store the preheat rect to compare against in the future.
    self.previousPreheatRect = preheatRect;
}
}
```

## The last ran code before crashing as shown by the debugger

## Swift

```
func assetsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: NSArray) -> NSArray {
    if indexPaths.count == 0 {return []}

    let assets = NSMutableArray(capacity: indexPaths.count)
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
        assets.addObject(asset)
    }
    return assets
}
```

## Objective-C

```
- (NSArray *)assetsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths {
if (indexPaths.count == 0) { return nil; }

NSMutableArray *assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:indexPaths.count];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
    PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];
    [assets addObject:asset];
}

return assets;
}
```

## Error

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

## The last line before throwing the error. Which is not an optional value is

`let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset` which is in `assetsAtIndexPaths` method

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should unwrap optional value.

Answer (score 0):

If the crash is due to an undefined value in the Optional, the following will protect against that condition

```
if let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as? PHAsset {
   assets.addObject(asset)
}
```

if you replace this code with it inside your for loop

```
let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
assets.addObject(asset)
```

This is called Optional Binding as found in the Swift book:

> You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary constant or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while statements to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value into a constant or variable, as part of a single action. if and while statements are described in more detail in Control Flow.

Comment: `if let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as? PHAsset` that line was the line it last ran before throwing `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. If I don't run the `updateCachedAssets` function, the app works fine. But, the images keeps reloading

Comment: The syntax in the line that I've suggested is slightly different from your original syntax. Are you saying that you tried it and your app still crashes?

Comment: Yeah. It still crashes after doing that

Comment: Is it possible to  check `self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]` for null value?

Comment: Optional binding is the correct and concise way to handle a nil value inside an Optional. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.